# improve circle detection with unknown background

Tags: python, opencv

I am using the code below to cut image into small piece, each piece contain a circle. But the circle detection is not perfect, so I have to set the condition to mainttain only the pics that have circle. (Remove the pic that have only background of something else). So I tried to set to keep all the pics that have the center pixel bigger than a threshold. But the problem is I have to test in several images with different background, so sometime the center pixel need to be less than a threshold rather than bigger. (Depend on which one is brighter, the circle or the background).

So how can I do that?
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_array = np.array(img)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
DataShape = (80,80,3)

limit_data = []
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(cimg,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=15,param2=20,minRadius=10,maxRadius=25)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))[0,:]
print (len(circles))
j = 0
for i in circles:
    half = DataShape[0]//2
    zoom_data = img_array[i[1]-half:i[1]+half,i[0]-half:i[0]+half,:]
    if zoom_data.shape!=DataShape : continue
    czoom = cv2.cvtColor(zoom_data, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    czoomarr = np.array(zoom_data)
    #print (np.amax(czoomarr))
    if czoom[40,40] > 60:
         cv2.imwrite("cut/"+"%d.jpg"%(j),zoom_data)
         limit_data.append(zoom_data)
         print(len(limit_data))
         j = j+1
```

And here is two of my pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: imho, there are no circles in your images...

Comment: you maybe could use otsu thesholding to find a good threshold

Comment: Well, I mean circle in relative meaning. :D And what is otsu thresholding?

Comment: otsu uses some logic to find a "good" threshold automatically. You can use it with opencv's threshold function with the right parameters.